# Mysql query match exact word and remove that exact word from database

Tags: mysql, regex

I am using self join query here with case when statement. my query should work like it matches whole exact word from database not should match word within word.

After i finding exact word match it should remove that word from that string and update database.

When i match it can match exact word but problem is it update word within word. please see my query here.

```
update table1 a
left join table1 b on
    (a.id = b.id)
SET a.column = CASE
         WHEN b.column2 IS NOT NULL THEN REPLACE(a.column, 'ich', '')
       END       
       where (a.column REGEXP '[[:<:]]ich[[:>:]]')
```

**Original string(column)** :

```
ich fühlte mich beobachtet, konnte nicht in ruhe auswählen
```

**above query output string(column)** :

```
fühlte m beobachtet,  nt  ruhe auswählen
```

**output must come(column) :**

```
fühlte mich beobachtet, konnte nicht in ruhe auswählen
```

please suggest solution.It should remove "**ich**" word only because just matched one whole word only but it is removing word within word.

Comment: Try `REPLACE(concat(' ', a.column, ' '), ' ich ', ' ')`.

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  thanks its working

Comment: Posted, please check.

Comment: But what happens when `column2 IS NULL`?  But what if there is punctuation next to `ich`?  You are better off doing the task in application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In above query you are replacing `'ich' to ''` not a exact word so it is taking ich character sequence in whole string , If you want to exact word then you can manage exact word with space `like ' ich '`.

Your modified query will be,

**Option 1**

```
update table1 a
left join table1 b on
    (a.id = b.id)
SET a.column = CASE
         WHEN b.column2 IS NOT NULL THEN REPLACE(a.column, ' ich ', ' ')
       END       
       where (a.column REGEXP '[[:<:]]ich[[:>:]]')
```

**Option 2**: you can use concat function also , here you can add space before or after that word which you want to search.

```
update table1 a
    left join table1 b on
        (a.id = b.id)
    SET a.column = CASE
             WHEN b.column2 IS NOT NULL THEN REPLACE(concat(' ', a.column, ' '), ' ich ', ' ') 
           END       
           where (a.column REGEXP '[[:<:]]ich[[:>:]]')
```

**Note:** I'll recommend you use option two to prevent fake space.

Answer (score 0):

You may work around that limitation with

```
REPLACE(concat(' ', a.column, ' '), ' ich ', ' ')
```

The thing is, you may add fake spaces to the entries and to the word that should be replaced as a whole word. Not a 100% solution, but can work in most cases.